# How to import a node module VS use the browser api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, es6-modules, rollupjs

In a TS package designed to run in both nodeJS and a browser, I want to access secure random generation from either `crypto.getRandomValues`(browser) or `crypto.randomFillSync`(node).

In `package.json`, I have `"type": "module"`, my whole library uses ES6 imports (so require is not defined).
I use `tsc` to compile the regular node package and rollup to pack it into a UMD for browser.

Unfortunately, the node crypto module must be imported to be usable. The `import` statement cannot "hide" inside `if`, so it will crash when run in the browser.

```js
if(typeof crypto == "object"){
  fillRandom = crypto.getRandomValues
}
else{ //node
  import crypto from "crypto" //Err: Cannot use import outside a module (browser)
  fillRandom = crypto.randomFillSync
}
```

With commonJS I could simply use `require("crypto")`, but I have already fully commited to using ESM modules.

I imagine I could swap out this part of the code before compiling TS for browser/node, so both versions would have the code that makes sense in their enviroment, but I don't know how, it seems  a bit overkill.

**Is there a way?**

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. It's frustrating that something so simple is so problematic.

Comment: You could try spinning up a web worker, which has access to `crypto`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues

Answer (score 2):

Hi [**@Franartur Čech**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11488133/franartur-%c4%8cech),

> An import declaration can only be used at the top level of a module.

So, You just need to add **await** for your module.

```js
if (typeof crypto == "object") {
    fillRandom = crypto.getRandomValues
} else {
    const { randomFillSync } = await import("crypto");
}
```

There is another similar type of answer I find on the internet. With the `window.crypto` property, it is available in modern browsers that support the Web Cryptography API, I guess.

```js
if (typeof window !== "undefined" && typeof window.crypto === "object") {
  fillRandom = (buffer) => {
    window.crypto.getRandomValues(buffer);
  };
} else {
  // node.js environment
  const crypto = require("crypto");
  fillRandom = crypto.randomFillSync;
}
```

Comment: Well, I upvoted but there are shortcomings. In my case `esbuild` will plainly refuse to build that for the browser, assuming an error because the `crypto` "module" is not available at compile time. Secondly, it will cause all methods depending on crypto to become async as well, which might be a bit of refactoring in the best case and be problematic because of third party libs in the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is some good news at least. In the latest Node v19, the `crypto` module is at last a global, referencing WebCrypto!

https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/42083

...that was time.

In other words, with Node >= 19, you can just use `crypto` out of the box like in the browser:

`fillRandom = crypto.getRandomValues`

And for all other node versions < 19 you will need funky non-trivial workarounds.